# OAuth 2.0 call from android

Tags: java, android, curl, oauth-2.0

I need to execute a PUT and GET request ( both return a json ) in Android because I have to implement a API. Now given the following access token:

"access_token": "KVKfzF/bti73cVr5rnGqz6qrH+oFK2Nr1y4qudUKfhs=",
"refresh_token": "m4bOdbVLnSWevo762oNpECMMXqMpyWFrw8dkbWaPN9I=",
"expires_in": 36000,
"token_type": "bearer"

How can i submit a GET and PUT request through an Android app? Also is it possible to execute an equivalent curl statement?

```
curl www.gumbox.co/api/v1/note -d "title=Hello World" -d "type=1" -H"Authorization: Bearer KVKfzF/bti73cVr5rnGqz6qrH+oFK2Nr1y4qudUKfhs="
```

Both the ways are possible and return json through terminal. I want equivalent android code. Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android -- search around for better questions. "http request"

Comment: @MarcoAcierno but i dont want to simply put a HTTP request.. I need the correct code.. Im @ a hackathon